# The context of "Don't be ridiculous"

Tags: meaning-in-context, discourse-context

Parents and their kid are shopping in a mall. The kid asks their parents for toys, but they refuse. Eventually he sits on the ground and cries over out loud. The parents feel humiliated because of many spectators around.
In this context, "Come on! Please, **Don't be ridiculous**" is adequate?

Comment: Is it the child speaking or the parents?

Comment: The parents speaking to the kid

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an acceptable phrase to use in this context. However, there are other phrases that might be more common:

- Stop making a scene!
- Don't be such a baby!

And so on, depending on your parenting style of course!

The phrase *don't be ridiculous* is probably more commonly used in response to something somebody has **said**, rather than something they are **doing**:

> A: Did you know the moon is made of cheese?

> B:  Don't be ridiculous!

Answer (score 0):

*Ridiculous* comes from a Latin word meaning *to laugh*, so the literal meaning is *so unlikely or inappropriate as to make people laugh*. "Don't be ridiculous" would be said to someone who is behaving in a silly way or has said something silly.